# Visual Studio 2013 Select Where Date = Today's Date

Tags: gridview, visual-studio-2013, webforms, sqldatasource

Hello I am trying to display information using an SqlDataSource to a Gridview where it only displays data where the date is = to today however I'm struggling to get it work I have tried several different ways. Can anyone give me a hand with this please?

[Screenshot of current SQL Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPGZQ.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some reading I found that using a LINQ Query to output to the grid view a lot easier and returns exactly what I needed.

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Using myEntities As New BackupsEntities

        Dim today = DateAndTime.Today



        Dim successfuldaily = From BackupTable In myEntities.BackupTables
                              Where BackupTable.Status = "Success"
                              Where BackupTable.Date = today
                              Select BackupTable






        GridView1.DataSource = successfuldaily.ToList
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End Using
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's not recommended using SqlDataSources, for you are getting a layer overflow giving for the presentation layer the responsability to know your SQL Queries.

The way you solve is correct, but it's recommended using some ORM Mapping framework like Entity Framework or NHibernate.